# How to drop observations conditionally with same values in R

Tags: r, subset

I'm trying to subset dataframe with age condition. However I want it to be conditional on multiple observations.

The dataframe has 10 observations, with variables 'household id', 'household relation', 'age'. 'Household id' is household number that has been uniquely assigned to each house. 'Household realation' is position of a person in the household. '1' means that the person is head of the household. '2' means that he/she is the spouse of that household. 'Age' is age of the person.

```
    Household_id     Household_relation    Age 
1            2                1            27
2            2                2            34  
3            4                1            22
4            4                2            23
5            7                2            21
6            7                1            29  
7            9                1            33  
8            9                2            34
9           11                1            31
10          11                2            29
```

So the data is made of couples of each household. 
I want to drop couples that are both not in 20s. So if one of them are in 20s, they stay(therefore household id 2 stays). But if they are both not in 20s, I want to drop them from the data(for example, household id 9 should be dropped).
So the subsetting process should be conditional on two observations each time.

Since my real data has more then 10000 observations, the syntax should be short enough to subset all the data. I tried to do this using 'for' loop, but couldn't figure out how.

How can I do this procedure in R?

below are my reproducible example code.

```
Household_id <- c(2,2,4,4,7,7,9,9,11,11)
Household_relation <- c(1,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2)
Age <- c(27,34,22,23,21,29,33,34,31,29)
data <- data.frame(Household_id, Household_relation, Age)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `dplyr` we can use `filter` to keep the groups that has `any` of the members in their 20's.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   group_by(Household_id) %>%
   filter(any(Age >= 20 & Age < 30))

# Household_id  Household_relation   Age
#         <dbl>              <dbl> <dbl>
#1            2                  1    27
#2            2                  2    34
#3            4                  1    22
#4            4                  2    23
#5            7                  2    21
#6            7                  1    29
#7           11                  1    31
#8           11                  2    29
```

---

The base R equivalent with `ave` would be

```
data[as.logical(ave(data$Age, data$Household_id, FUN = function(x)
                                                  any(x >= 20 & x < 30))), ]
```

Comment: That is brilliant. Why didn't I think of group_by function!

Comment: beat me to it. I had `x <- data %>% group_by(Household_id) %>% filter(any(substr(Age, 1, 1) == 2))`

Comment: after subsetting, can I use 'ungroup' command to ungroup the data and do regression? or do I not need to ungroup before doing regression?

Comment: @DanielCho I am not sure, but I think it should not make any difference if you do regression directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can, of course, translate this to "data.table" like:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(data)[, .SD[any(Age >= 20 & Age < 30)], Household_id]
#    Household_id Household_relation Age
# 1:            2                  1  27
# 2:            2                  2  34
# 3:            4                  1  22
# 4:            4                  2  23
# 5:            7                  2  21
# 6:            7                  1  29
# 7:           11                  1  31
# 8:           11                  2  29
```

Comment: This works well too! I am not used to data.table syntax but It works well for sure.